# Creating a dictionary of methods using function decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, methods, python-decorators

I have a class PQR with various methods. I want to tag each method with a variable, and create a dictionary from the methods of the class using the tags of each method as its key. Something like this:

```
class PQR:

    @tag_method(5)
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        # does something

    @tag_method(3)
    @staticmethod
    def do_something_else():
        # does something else


def get_dict(class_with_decorator_tag_method):
    # some code which returns {5:PQR.do_something, 3:PQR.do_something_else} if class_with_decorator_tag_method=PQR

d = get_dict(PQR)
d[5]()    # does something
d[3]()    # does something else
```

How do I implement something like this in Python 2.7?

EDIT:
The comments made me realize that the information I gave might be insufficient.

So here - I'm trying to create an abstract class called App, which has a meta class EventHandlerMethods. Here's the basic structure:

```
class App:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    class EventHandlerMethods:

        @tag_method(3)
        def on_event_3():
            # changes something in App object

        @tag_method(5)
        def on_event_5():
            # changes something else in app object

    def __init__(self):
        event_handler = get_dict(EventHandlerMethods)  

    def on_event(event_type, *args, **kwargs):
        event_handler[event_type](*args, **kwargs)
```

This way, when App is inherited, to define event handling methods, a programmer just needs to add those methods to the meta class.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Why are they in a class? Are they all going to be staticmethods? If so, your decorator could probably implement that. Or move them out of the class.

Comment: what have you tried? also, why wouldn't you just put the dictionary on the class and populate it then?

Comment: `tag_method` can simply assign an attribute to the function and the `get_dict` uses `dir` to obtain all the methods of the class. Which part is causing you troubles?

Comment: I did not know that functions can take attributes in python. That greatly simplifies this. Thanks. :)